# Service could not be started on reboot

Tags: windows, wcf, service, reboot

I've programmed a small service running as Windows Service. On most computers this works well, but there are a few computers, where the service sometimes does not start when the computer is rebootet.

It is no problem to start the service after the boot. Just the automatic start right on boot does not work.

I already tried to put the service into delayed start, but this didn't Change anything. The service still sometimes not starts on reboot.

The service is running on a local service account and does just open a few WFC services and wait for connections.

Comment: Try logging on service start into application event log, or may be it is already doing it. Check them you might get the solution

Comment: @Sam Did you get this resolved in the end?

Comment: Actually, no, not really :/